# Нахождение самого длинного слова в строке

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте 
У меня есть проблема, есть код, но он работает не совсем так как надо.

Задание: Создать текстовый файл. Слова в файле отделены пробелами , запятыми , точками. В каждом предложении определить самое длинное слово. Создать новый текстовый файл , в котором каждое предложение размещается в отдельной строке и начинается с числа , равной длине самого длинного слова в нем, по которым идет именно это слово. Вывести содержимое исходного и созданного файлов.

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void infile(char*);
void outfile(char*);
void result(char*, char*);

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char* f1 = "f1.txt";
    char* f2 = "f2.txt";
    infile(f1);
    result(f1, f2);
    outfile(f1);    
    outfile(f2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void infile(char* name) { //Ф-ия заполнения файла. 
    string str;
    ofstream file(name);
    cout << "Заполните файл " << name << ":\n";
    while (true) {
        if (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)) {
            getline(cin, str);
            file << str << "\n";
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    file.close();
}

void outfile(char* name) {  //Ф-ия вывода содержимого файла. 
    string str;
    ifstream file(name);
    cout << "\nСодержание файла " << name << ":\n";
    while (getline(file, str)) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}

void result(char* name1, char* name2) {  //Ф-ия поиска самого длинного слова в файле.
    string str;
    ofstream file2(name2);
    ifstream file1(name1);
    while (getline(file1, str)) { //Записываем файл в строку str
        istringstream ss(str);
        string sentence;
        while (getline(ss, sentence, '.')) {  //Записываем в строку, подстроку до разделителя(вот тут ошибка, как я понимаю)
            istringstream ws(sentence);
            string curr, longest;
            while (ws >> curr)  
                if (curr.size() > longest.size()) 
                    longest = curr
            sentence = sentence.substr(sentence.find_first_not_of(" "));    
            file2 << longest.size() << " | " << longest << " | " << sentence << endl;
        }  
    }
    file1.close();
    file2.close();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда заполняешь первый файл, и делаешь перенос строки нажатием кнопки "Enter", программа считает что это конец предложения, хотя, конец должен быть только там где точка.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вывод из текста самого длинного и короткого слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/376213/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл, выбирающий из потока предложения, не должен быть вложен в цикл, который считывает из файла по одной строке за раз. Разрыв между строками одновременно разрывает и то предложение, внутри которого он случается.

Для того, чтобы цикл по предложениям работал правильно, необходимо перед его началом считать весь файл целиком, избавившись от разрывов между строками. Это можно сделать множеством способов. Например, вот так.

```
stringstream cs;

string line; char last = ' ';
while (getline(file1, line)) {
    if (!line.empty() && last != ' ' && line.front() != ' ') cs << ' ';
    cs << line;
    last = line.back();
}
```

Comment: @Shamow
извините, не совсем понимаю куда проверку на разрывы поставить :(

Comment: @thundermind Какую проверку на разрывы?

Comment: ну, ваш этот код не избавляется от разрывов?

Comment: @thundermind Избавляется. Каждый вызов `getline` кладёт в `line` новую строку из файла, а разрывы пропускает.

Comment: то есть ее вместо `while (getline(file1, str)) ` использовать?

Comment: я в этих строках совсем не силен, извините :(

Comment: @thundermind Кого её? Я не понимаю, в чём проблема...

Comment: @thundermind Это очень плохо. Работа со строками - это один из краеугольных камней программирования.

Comment: да я только-только начал учить их :)
ну, этот кусок кода я не понимаю куда мне вставить, дабы все работало нормально.

Comment: @thundermind Я думаю, что тут нужно немного подумать самому. Считайте, что это такое упражнение для самостоятельного выполнения. Как только станет понятно, что этот код делает, сразу же станет понятно и то, куда именно его нужно вставить.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо огромное :)

Answer (score 3):

```
void file_stat(istream& i, ostream& o){
   string t, s;
   int    c;

   do {

     c = i.get();
     if((c == '.') || (c == '!') || (c == '?')){

        if(t.length() > 0){
            o << t.length() << "\t|\t" << t.c_str();
            o << endl;
        }

        s = t = "";
    } else if(isalpha(c))
        s += c;
     else {
        if(s.length() > t.length())
            t = s;
        s = "";
     }

   } while(c != EOF);

   o.flush();
 }

 //***

 ifstream i("input.txt");
 ofstream o("output.txt");
 file_stat(i, o);
 i.close();
 o.close();
```

p.s. шпальте.