# Поиск самых длинных и комбинированных слов в файле - C++

Tags: c++, ms-word

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть такая задача:

1. Найти 2 самых длинных комбинированных слова
2. Найти все комбинированные слова в файле
3. Подсчитать общее количество слов в файле

То есть, я вписываю в программу файл, в котором содержатся слова по одному в строке без пробелов, допустим 1000 слов. Необходимо что бы программа читала все слова, находила обычные слова (например cat) и комбинированное слово (на пример catdog). Программа должна распознавать это комбинированное слово и записывала в массив для подсчета, и из всех комбинированных должна найти 2 самых длинных.

У меня есть начальный код, программа просто ищет 2 самых длинных слова, но не комбинированные:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
struct Lcompare : binary_function<string, string, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const string& p, const string& q) const
    {
        return p.size() > q.size();
    }
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    multiset<string, Lcompare > words;
    ifstream ifs("words.txt");
    if (!ifs)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка, файл не найден \nПожалуйста повторите попытку" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (!ifs.eof())
        {
            string s;
            ifs >> s;
            words.insert(s);
        }
        // вывести на экран
        multiset<string, Lcompare >::iterator it = words.begin();
        for (int i = 1;  i <= 2 && it != words.end(); i++)
            cout << *it++ << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Слово вычленить не проблема, похоже вы уже убедились. А вот с "комбинированым" человек может различить, а машина? Нужен или словарь (более менее реально), либо формула (более фантастично).

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Вывод из текста самого длинного и короткого слова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/376213/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что ваше предложение - массив `char`. Тогда все что вам нужно - подсчитать количество пробелов и прибавить 1 - это и будет количество слов. Если же перед предложением или после может также стоять пробел, то нужно это учитывать.

Если случай усложняется знаками препинания, или если пробелов может быть несколько, то тогда можно составить массив из знаков-разделителей (к примеру **, . : ;** И в цикле проверять, не является ли текущий символ разделителем. Если символ является разделителем, то увеличиваем счетчик слов. Также нужно учитывать то, что может встретиться запятая и пробел, значит стоит сделать проверку: если предыдущий знак не был разделителем, а текущий - разделитель, то тогда увеличиваем счетчик слов.

А готовый код здесь вам вряд-ли кто-то даст

Comment: Задам вопрос иначе:

Comment: Полностью перефразировал вопрос.