# Поиск самого длинного слова в строке. С++

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно найти самое длинное слово в строке. BAЖНО! Без  класса string! проблема в том что код, не работает. и мне выводит всю строку вместо самого длинного слова

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <locale>
    #include <cstring> 
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char S[100];
    int n, i, k, kol, max = 0, y,g,j=0;
    cin.getline(S, 100);
    int p;
    i = 0;
    for (int l=0;l<strlen(S);l++)//проходимся по длине строки, и ищем пробелы, и после каждого меряем слово.
    {
    while (S[l] != ' ')
    {
        if (S[l] == ' ')
        {
            p=l;
            l++;
        }
        else
        {

            do
            {
                l++;
            } while (S[l] != ' ');    //длина слова
             kol = strlen(S)-l-p; //длина слова  //p последний пробел
            if (kol > max)
            {
                l++;
                     ///max word
                max = kol;
            }

        }

     }
    }
    for (n; n<k; n++)
    {
        cout << S[n];
    }
    cout << " - самое длинное слово" << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А разве ваш код компилируется?...

Comment: @Harry,да компилируется

Comment: Странно, для этой строки - `kol = strlen(S)-l-p;` - нет объявления `p`...

Comment: @Harry привет. есть у него p )

Comment: @perfect Где? Вот я тупо copy-paste делаю: http://ideone.com/2bGOon - результат смотрите сами...

Comment: @Harry на 19ю строку посмотрите

Comment: @perfect Ну и что? Это объявление ограничено блоком, и в 21 строке никакого `p` уже нет...

Comment: @Harry так не известно какой это компилятор и как он настроен. может у него стек вообще не очищается

Comment: @perfect В таком случае этот компилятор **не соответствует стандарту C++**, и на этом можно прекращать любые обсуждения...

Comment: @Harry да с этим не поспоришь. новички часто занижают уровень проверки, что бы не думать об ошибках. лишь бы собралось )

Comment: @perfect Да ну не может ЭТО собраться никак! Это не warning, это полноценный error! Просто ТС или ошибся при переносе в SO кода, или даже не пробовал его компилировать. Не верю я в компилятор, который этот код пропустит. Покажите такой - даже интересно посмотреть на уродца...

Comment: @Harry сам таким не страдал. просто предположил, что компилятор можно настроить таким образом для обзора памяти. (для отладки)

Comment: @Harry, я сейчас перепишу ето, т.к. я ето  исправил, предыдущую версию кода скинул, извините

Comment: @Harry вот видишь есть p =))

Comment: @perfect Теперь есть :)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вывод из текста самого длинного и короткого слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/376213/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на мой вкус сложновато...
Я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    const int STRLEN = 200;
    char s[STRLEN];
    cin.getline(s, STRLEN);

    size_t maxlen = 0;
    char * maxidx = nullptr;

    for(char * c = s; *c;)
    {
        while(*c == ' ') ++c;
        if (*c == 0) break;
        char * begin = c;
        while(*c && *c != ' ') ++c;
        if (maxlen < (c - begin))
        {
            maxlen = c - begin;
            maxidx = begin;
        }
    }
    if (maxlen == 0)
    {
        cout << "Empty line!\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *(maxidx+maxlen) = 0;
        cout << maxidx;
    }
}
```

Comment: , `*(maxidx+maxlen) = 0`,что значит ета звездочка?, кроме того что указатель. Тоесть,как понять ету строку.

Comment: Обрезаем слово по первому пробелу за ним. Можно выводить `maxlen-1` символов, начиная с `maxidx`, но мне было проще обрезать строку после самого длинного слова и выводить его целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что это поможет вам, вот рабочий код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // сторка
    char * theString = " dsjfkd1 sdf2 dsfkdsj3   sdfjsdkjfdsjf4   d5 ";
    char * theLetter = theString; // здесь будем хранить адрес очередного символа начинаяя с первого
    unsigned counter = 0, // счетчик подсчета букв в слове
        storage = 0; // здесь будем хранить количество букв самого большого слова

    while (*theLetter) { // повторять пока не прийдет нулевой символ конца
        theLetter++; // увеличиваем очерной адрес на размер символа

        if (*theLetter != ' ') // если не пробел
            counter++; // увеличиваем счетчик
        else
            if (counter > storage) { // если букв больше чем мы знали раньше ,
                storage = counter;   // то сохраним это число
                counter = 0; // апотом обнулим счетчик подсчета
            }
    }

    cout << storage << endl; // результат
}
```

Comment: `char* foo = "bar";`? несерьёзно