# Удаление и вывод самого короткого слова

Tags: c++

Как вместо вывода самого короткого слова произвести его удаление из `in` и вывести остальное в `out`?

```
void findShortestWord(const char* in, char* out) {
    int len = strlen(in);

    int beginWord = 0;
    int lengthWord = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        while ( (in[i] == ' ') && ( in[i] != '\0')  ) i++;
        int begin = i;
        while ( (in[i] != ' ') && (in[i] != '\0') ) i++;
        int end = i;
        char tmp[256];
        for(int j = begin, k=0; j < end; j++, k++)
            tmp[k] = in[j];
        tmp[end - begin] = '\0';

        int currentLen = end - begin;
        if ( (currentLen < lengthWord) || (lengthWord == 0) ) {
            lengthWord = currentLen;
            beginWord = begin;
        }
    }

    for (int i = beginWord, k = 0; i < beginWord + lengthWord; i++, k++)
        out[k] = in[i];

    out[lengthWord] = '\0';
}

    char* out2;

    for(int z = 0; z < beginWord; z++)
        out2[z] = in[z];

    int x2 = beginWord + lengthWord + 1;

    for(int x = beginWord; x <= len - lengthWord; x++) {
        out2[x] = in[x2];
        x2++;
    }
```

Comment: У вас есть исходная строка, есть индексы начала и конца самого короткого. Нужно просто создать новую строку с длинной = длинна исходной - длинна самого короткого слова. Потом скопировать туда символы из исходной строки до начала самого короткого слова и символы исходной строки после самого короткого слова.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Rikitikitavi Можете мне помочь? я дополнил вопрос. У меня ошибка на x2++

Comment: По этому коду ничего не могу сказать. Он в принципе до инкремента `x2` дойти не может потому что память для `out2` не выделена. Если это не весь код то возможно  где то в индексах ошибка и происходит выход за пределы массива

Comment: @Rikitikitavi Дело было в памяти

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вывод из текста самого длинного и короткого слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/376213/23044)