# Найти самое длинное слово, в котором нет заданной буквы

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, символы

Имеется файл, в нём написаны слова, каждое с новой строки. С клавиатуры вводится буква. Нужно вывести на экран самое длинное слово, в котором нет этой буквы. Я написала код, который выводит все буквы, кроме заданной, но это далеко не то, что нужно...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/* Файл: слова. С клавы вводится буква. Самое длинное слово, в котором нет этой буквы*/



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char s[100];
char letter;
cin>>letter;    
    ifstream f("in.txt"); 

    while(!f.eof())
    {
        f>>s;
        for (int n=0; s[n]!=0; n++){
            if (s[n]!=letter)
            cout<<s[n]<<endl;
        }
    }

    f.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Я не могу понять, как сделать это с чаровскими переменными. А как проводить такие операции со стрингами, не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить задачу!

Comment: использование std::string допускается?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вывод из текста самого длинного и короткого слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/376213/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уже написали половину, теперь исправьте

```
for (int n=0; s[n]!=0; n++){
            if (s[n]!=letter)
            cout<<s[n]<<endl;
        }
```

на:

```
bool b = false;
for (int n=0; s[n]!=0; n++){
            if (s[n] == letter) b = true;           
        }
if (b) continue;

else {// добавляем строку в массив (контейнер) строк };
```

дальше с помощью функции `strlen()` определите длину каждой строки и найдете самую длинную строку.

Если же вместо массива использовать `std::string`, решать будет проще

Answer (score 0):

C использованием std::string вариант:

```
char c;
cin >> c;
string s;
string word;
while (cin >> s)
{
    bool f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        if (s[i] == c)
        {
            f = 1;
            break;
        }

    if (!f && s.size() > word.size())
        word = s;
}
cout << word;
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, только я исправила (cin>>s) на (f>>s), всё-таки слова вводятся из файла, а не с клавиатуры:)
И ещё один момент: не подскажете, к какой библиотеке относится функция size? Мне просто надо будет преподавателю объяснить весь алгоритм