# Поиск самого длинного слова в тексте C (СИ)

Tags: c

Почему то переменная maxLengthStr перезаписывается и самое длинное слово сбрасывается в момент вывода.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    FILE *fp;
    char str[60];

    // открытие файла для чтения
    fp = fopen("/Users/artemmelnik/Documents/lab2/lab2/text.txt" , "r");

    // проверяем на ошибки открытия файла
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Ошибка чтения файла");
        return(-1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    char *istr;

    // Переменная в которую мы будем сохранять последнее максимальное значение
    int maxLength = 0;
    int currentLength = 0;
    char *maxLengthStr = "";

    if ( fgets (str, 60, fp) != NULL ) {

        while( fgets ( str, 60, fp ) != NULL ) {

            // Разделяем текущую строку на части (слова)
            istr = strtok (str, " ");

            // Выделение последующих частей
            while (istr != NULL) {

                currentLength = strlen(istr);

                printf("%d %d \n", currentLength, maxLength);

                if (currentLength >= maxLength) {
                    maxLengthStr = istr;
                    maxLength    = currentLength;

                    printf("%s \n", maxLengthStr);
                }

                // Выделение очередной части строки
                istr = strtok (NULL, " ");

                //printf("%d \n", maxLength);
            }

        }

        printf("Найдено самое длинное слово: %s(%d) \n", maxLengthStr, maxLength);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);

}
```

Comment: if (currentLength > maxLength) {
                maxLengthStr = istr;
                maxLength    = currentLength;

                printf("%s \n", maxLengthStr);
            }

Comment: [примеры программ на Си//С++ для поиска самых коротких/длинных слов во вводе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/376485/23044)